# Contact form not displaying on the page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Hey I am trying to create a contact page for my rails app. I created a contact model:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

a contact controller:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  skip_after_action :verify_authorized

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
  end

end
```

ran a migration :

```
class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :object
      t.text :content

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I also created a route

```
resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]
```

and created a view:

```
<div class="banner">
<div class="container">
<div class= "col-xs-12">
<%simple_form_for @contact do |t|%>
  <%= t.error_notification %>
  <%= t.input :email, label: 'Votre email' %>
  <%= t.input :object, label: 'Objet' %>
  <%= t.input :content, label: 'Votre Message' %>
   <%= t.button :submit, value: "Soumettre ce tournoi à validation",  class: "btn-primary marge-bas" %>
  <% end -%>
</div>
</div></div>
```

the link to my contacts/new works fine but my contact form is not displaying on the page.

Comment: `<%simple_form_for @contact do |t|%> ` equal missing in front of this line

Comment: it should be `<%=simple_form_for @contact do |t|%>`

Comment: thank you, I think I need to stop coding for a few hours :/

Comment: its very common mistake...will suggest you to delete this post..else you may have to face too much negative votes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `<%=simple_form_for @contact do |t|%>`

Answer (score 1):

You should write your simple_form_for like 
`<%= simple_form_for %>`